# multi-class logistic regression using sklearn (representing y as multi-class)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm working on a what I thought was a fairly simple machine learning problem.

In this problem the y (label) I'm wanting to classify is a multi-class value.  In this dataset I have 6 possible choices.

I've been using the preprocessing.LabelBinarizer() function to pivot my y set to an array of ones or zeros in hopes that this would be sufficient (e.g. [0 0 0 0 0 1]).

This code below fails on the model.fit() due to a ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [ 217 1302] || 1302 is 217*6 BTW

```
lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
api_y = lb.fit_transform(df['gear'])
y = pd.DataFrame(api_y)
y = np.ravel(y)
```

It seems that the binarizer returns results that appear like 6 columns to the algorithm instead of 1 column containing an array of 6 digits.

I've tried to force it into an array model using the code below but then the fit function bails for another reason: ValueError: Unknown label type array([array[0,1,0,0,0]), arrary([0,1,0,0...])

```
lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
api_y = lb.fit_transform(df['gear'])
y_list = []
for x in api_y:
   item = {'gear': np.array(x)}
   y_list.append(item)
y = pd.DataFrame(y_list)
print("after changing to binary classes array y is "+repr(y.shape))
y = np.ravel(y)
```

I also tried the sklearn_pandas.DataFrameMapper to no avail as it also created 6 distinct fields vs. an array of 6 values represented as one field.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated...full version of what I thought was right posted here for clarity:

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from patsy import dmatrices
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn import metrics
import sklearn_pandas
#
# load traing data taken from 2 years of strava rides
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("gear_train.csv")
#
# Prepare data for logistic regression
#
y, X = dmatrices('gear ~ distance + moving_time + total_elevation_gain + average_speed + max_speed + average_cadence + has_heartrate + device_watts', df, return_type="dataframe")
#
# Fix up y to be a flattened array of 1 column (binary array?)
#
lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
api_y = lb.fit_transform(df['gear'])
y = pd.DataFrame(api_y)
y = np.ravel(y)
#
# run the logistic regression
#
model = LogisticRegression()
model = model.fit(X, y)
score = model.score(X, y)
#
# evaluate the model by splitting into training and testing data sets
#
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
model2 = LogisticRegression()
model2.fit(X_train, y_train)
predicted = model2.predict(X_test)
print("predicted="+repr(lb2.inverse_transform(predicted)))
print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, predicted))
#
# do a 10-fold CV test to see if this model holds up
#
scores = cross_val_score(LogisticRegression(), X, y, scoring='accuracy', cv=10)
print(scores.mean())enter code here
```

Comment: Your question is hard to read. You also misinterpret the error. ```Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples``` means, that something is wrong with the first dimension, not the second (features/columns). Also much of the code in the first part does not make much sense. Why prepare preprocessing object, when just training on df-frame (whery no y was processed). It might be easier to stick to pure-numpy arrays for the moment. Consider working on some scikit-learn tutorials first before trying your own data to get a grasp on what's going on.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback.  I'm only using the preprocessing logic because I'm of the impression that my y must be converted to an array of 0 1 based on the number of classes I'm trying to identify.  The X data isn't being processed at all...

Comment: I believe I solved the issue.  I was assuming the fit function could fit all classes in the same function call.  If I iterate and have models for each class it seems to work.  I then just find the model that predicts the highest probability...

Comment: Final update given I figured this out about a month ago.  Because my Y column had values that included text e.g. 'b12345' the system attempts make this like a category field.  Once I made the key only integers it worked fine as a multi-class classification in one predict call.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of my problem was y field contained string values instead of numeric.  For example b12345 as a key instead of 12345.  Once I changed that to use LabelEncoding and Decoding it worked like a champ.